# Show application in foreground from a background agent

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, background-agents

Is it possible to start an application in the foreground from the background agent? 
Or is it only possible to show toasts ?

thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only update tiles, or show toasts from a background agent. (With the exception of the Audio background agents, which can control audio as well).

You cannot start a app from a background agent. Showing a toast, will allow the user to click on the toast, which then in turn will start the application.